# Build a website in sitecore and make it offline

Tags: sitecore

I want build site using Sitecore(7.2) and also make it offline. Our requirement is not to use headless CMS. Is there any way to build or make it offline?

Comment: Sitecore 6.7 does not exist, current version is 9.x, but what do you mean with offline?

Comment: Corrected version, it is 7.2 For offline, when internet connection not available site should work for user.

Comment: Sitecore is scalable you can run it in multiple datacenters,

Answer (score 1):

Internet websites cannot be delivered 'offline' without having all possible data delivered to the device so that it no longer needs to connect to the internet. This sounds less like a website, and more like an app that somebody would install?

If so, you probably DO need to look at headless and building an app that connects to the APIs for updates.

You might need to be more specific about the business use case because it seems contradictory to want to use a web application software that delivers web content, without using headless, and works without the web.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested that internet websites cannot work offline so either you have an app or intranet website.

Considering as an app you can consume sitecore OData apis for Content/Media however it will not work for Presentations and you have to implement your own mobile designs based on Xamarin or native.

For odata related information you can refer below link:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-odata-item-service.html

Once you get the response from api, you can locally store it in your local db of app